# React Native The development server returned response error code: 500

Tags: react-native

[Screenshot of the virtual android device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kp6nf.png)

I am using Android Studio to create a virtual device for testing my React Native app. How can I fix this bug?

Edit1: I am using Windows. Check out the screenshot I added.

Comment: 500 could by occur by many issues so show the screen shot or share more details.
and can be possible you could not start npm

Comment: are you using windows?

Comment: It would help us answer your question, if you would provide more details and relevant code.

Comment: Above my question is the screenshot

Comment: Ok so that basically means your emulator could not find the server or the server rejected it. I&#39;m assuming you have already done &#39;npm start&#39; to start your server? If you have you should check if anything was in the output there. If that&#39;s all done check what port is the server running on and verify if that&#39;s the same port your emulator is trying to connect( 8081 in this case). Also if your port of different you can use 'adb reverse tcp:[port number] tcp:[port number]' to get your emulator to connect to the new port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using RN 0.56.0?
Apparently it is broken on Windows:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20331#issuecomment-406928234

You can try downgrading React-Native to 0.55.4 until it gets fixed.

Comment: Thanks alot ! That did fix it. For similar problems: Dont use" npm audit fix" after initializing the app, cause this will update RN to 0.56.0 again --> doesnt work again ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 'expo' to create and text your react native app, using it you can easily text your app in your own phone

heres a video explaining how to do it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yuaE8_nXmeY